# Logic Gates Implementation XOR, XNOR, and NAND gates using 1. AND IC 2. OR IC and 3. INVERTER IC

Tags: logic, tinkercad

Logic Gates Implementation XOR, XNOR, and NAND gates in Tinkercad using

1. one AND IC
2. one OR IC and
3. one INVERTER IC